# Trying to invoke a backdoor method in xamarin.uitests getting a failure

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

I have a xamarin.uitest project and an app project,
added in main activity in the app project:
MainLauncher = true and the method:

```
    [Export("MyInvokeMethod")]
    public void MyInvokeMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TEST");
    }
```

and in  my project test added a test that only invoke the method:

```
    [Test]
    public void MyInvokeMethodTest()
    {
        _app.Invoke("MyInvokeMethod");
    }
```

and I got :
System.Exception : Invoke for MyInvokeMethod failed with outcome: ERROR
No such method found: MyInvokeMethod()

I did everything like here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/frameworks/uitest/features/backdoors

Tried also in iOS:
in AppDelegate:
[image]

and in the test project:

```
[Test]
public void MyInvokeMethodTest()
{
    _app.Invoke("RefreshMethod:");
}
```

still nothing changed
what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether your Android App is deployed in its latest version to the emulator. Have in mind that it is only re-deployed automatically when you launch  the App itself in VS.

I guess most of us write tests like:

- Start writing a new UI Test in the UI Test project
- Add a new exported backdoor method for that UI Test into the Android project
- Invoke that method in the new UI Test
- Launch the new UI Test

In the last step the UI Test project + Android project will be compiled but the Android project will NOT be re-deployed to the emulator, because this is only triggered when launching the Android project itself.
So when the test now runs, it won't find the new backdoor method - because it's actually not yet there in the emulator. There is still the old version of the app.

To solve this, simply re-deploy the changed + compiled Android App manually to the emulator before starting the test (right click on the project + "Deploy")

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below. I made the test with the code you provided. It works well on my side.

1. Create the Xamarin.forms named `UITest` project and add the code below in MainActivity. It may be necessary to add a reference to the `Mono.Android.Export.dll` assembly in the Xamarin.Android project.

   ```
   public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
   {
      protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
             ......
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    [Java.Interop.Export("MyInvokeMethod")]
    public void MyInvokeMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TEST");
    }
   }
   ```
2. Create the UITest project named `UITest1` in the same solution. And then add reference with the `UITest.Android`.

- In `AppInitializer.cs`, add `ApkFile` in `StartApp` method.

  ```
  public static IApp StartApp(Platform platform)
   {
       if (platform == Platform.Android)
       {
           return ConfigureApp.Android
                .EnableLocalScreenshots()
                //.InstalledApp("com.companyname.app2")
                .ApkFile(@"....\UITest\UITest\UITest.Android\bin\Release\com.companyname.uitest.apk")
                .StartApp();
       }

       return ConfigureApp.iOS.StartApp();
   }
  ```
- Add the code below in `Tests.cs`.

  ```
  [Test]
    public void InvokeTest()
    {    
        // Invoke the backdoor method MainActivity.MyBackDoorMethod
        app.Invoke("MyInvokeMethod");
    }
  ```

3. In Test Explorer, you could run the test.

[image]

Comment: I have a project with android app and another test project not in the same solution
is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Add a project reference from the UITest project to the Xamarin.Android project.

Comment: My team leader didn't liked this solution so I didn't even tried :(

Comment: The code i provided used to fix the error in your issue. If you still have issue for this, feel free to let me know.

Comment: I also tried with iOS in different projects without success :(

Comment: when I did this in the same project it worked but why can't I do this in different projects :(